# Serve index.php if index.html is not present in directory without a trailing slash

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have an HTML website with subdirectories.

What I need is:

1. Access subdirectories with no trailing slash ie. (`example.com/blog`) not (`example.com/blog/`)
2. If `index.html` is absent under certain subdir, it should look for `index.php` instead.

`/blog/` page is a WordPress page with its own `.htaccess`.

Here's my current root `.htaccess`:

```
RewriteEngine on
ErrorDocument 404 /error/error404.html


DirectorySlash Off
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}%{REQUEST_URI}/index.html -f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /$1/index.html [L]
```

Wordpress `.htaccess` at `/blog/.htaccess`:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]
RewriteBase /blog/
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /blog/index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

(This is autogenerated by Wordpress)

As for now, html files can be access under certain subdir but not with index.php. What should I do?

Comment: _"What should I do?"_ - stop trying to use the rewrite engine, for what is [`DirectoryIndex`](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_dir.html#directoryindex)'s job to begin with ...?

Comment: And it should not have taken too much thinking to figure out that simply duplicating the existing condition & rule, and replacing `index.html` with `index.php`, would in all likelihood also have worked just fine.

Comment: Still the same. The subdirectory has .htaccess and it returns error 403 if I access with no trailing slash.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `DirectoryIndex` document lists the files to try to serve when requesting a directory. You don't need mod_rewrite for this.

However, to use the `DirectoryIndex` when you set `DirectorySlash Off` you need to manually append the trailing to the directory with an internal rewrite, otherwise, a 403 will be triggered even when that directory contains a `DirectoryIndex` document. (It is for this reason that mod_autoindex needs to be disabled to prevent accidental disclosure of information - the presence of a `DirectoryIndex` document is not sufficient to prevent the auto-generated directory listings when `DirectorySlash Off` is set.)

For example:

```
# Disable directory listings (mod_autoindex)
Options -Indexes

ErrorDocument 404 /error/error404.html

# Look for index.html then index.php in the directory being requested
DirectoryIndex index.html index.php

# Prevent mod_dir appending the trailing slash
DirectorySlash Off

RewriteEngine On

# If request a directory without a trailing slash then rewrite to append it
# This allows DirectoryIndex to work as intended
# - exclude the document root
RewriteCond $1 !/$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule (.+) $1/ [L]
```

Make sure the browser cache is cleared. mod_dir issues a 301 (permanent) redirect to append the trailing slash.

---

**UPDATE#1:**

> `/blog/` page is a WordPress page with its own `.htaccess`.

The problem with this is that when the rewrite engine is enabled in the subdirectory then it completely overrides the mod_rewrite directives in the parent config, so the slash is not appended and the directory index is not triggered (and the mod_rewrite directives are not processed because of the missing slash). (This feels a bit chicken and egg.)

The only way I have successfully resolved this is to move the WordPress directives into the parent config (making the necessary changes) and remove `/blog/.htaccess` altogether.

For example, append the following modified WordPress directives after the directives above:

```
# WordPress in "/blog" subdirectory
RewriteRule ^ - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]
RewriteRule ^blog/index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^blog/. /blog/index.php [L]
```

---

**UPDATE#2:**

> have URL with trailing slash to redirect to URL without trailing slash? like for example, if I visit `/about/` it should redirect to `/about`?

Yes, we can do this. Since we are removing the trailing slash from *everything*, including directories, this is essentially unconditional. The only caveat is that the rule to remove the trailing slash must only apply to direct requests from the client and not rewritten requests by the later rewrite, that appends the trailing slash to directories, which would otherwise result in a redirect loop.

*Aside:* You obviously need to ensure that all your internal links do not include the trailing slash, otherwise, the user will experience an external redirect (bad for SEO and your server).

We can do this by checking against the `REDIRECT_STATUS` environment variable, which is *empty* on the initial request, and set to `200` (as in 200 OK status) after the first successful rewrite (that appends the trailing slash to directories).

For example, the following should go immediately after the `RewriteEngine` directive, before the existing rewrite:

```
# Redirect direct requests to remove trailing slash from all URLs
RewriteCond %{ENV:REDIRECT_STATUS} ^$
RewriteRule (.+)/$ /$1 [R=302,L]
```

Test first with a 302 (temporary) redirect and change to a 301 (permanent) redirect once you have confirmed it works as intended. This is to avoid potential caching issues.

### Summary

With all the directives in place:

```
# Disable directory listings (mod_autoindex)
Options -Indexes

ErrorDocument 404 /error/error404.html

# Look for index.html then index.php in the directory being requested
DirectoryIndex index.html index.php

# Prevent mod_dir appending the trailing slash
DirectorySlash Off

RewriteEngine On

# Redirect direct requests to remove trailing slash from all URLs
RewriteCond %{ENV:REDIRECT_STATUS} ^$
RewriteRule (.+)/$ /$1 [R=301,L]

# If request a directory without a trailing slash then rewrite to append it
# - This allows DirectoryIndex to work as intended
# - Exclude the document root
RewriteCond $1 !/$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule (.+) $1/ [L]

# WordPress in "/blog" subdirectory
RewriteRule ^ - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]
RewriteRule ^blog/index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^blog/. /blog/index.php [L]
```

Comment: Now it's clear for me. But I get an Internal Server Error from homepage after trying your code. Homepage has index.html. Subdirectories/pages have index.html or index.php

Comment: @NicoReal I've modified the last rule block to exclude the document root, this may have been the cause of a rewrite loop (Internal Server Error).

Comment: @MrWhite Looking good so far. But problem is I can't access my Wordpress installation under a subdirectory with no trailing slash (/blog). I can access it with a trailing slash (/blog/). By the way, please also note that this Wordpress directory has a separate .htaccess file

Comment: @NicoReal Ah, yes, if you have a WordPress installation in a subdirectory with its own `.htaccess` file then this will indeed fail. The mod_rewrite directives in the subdirectory are going to override the parent directives and the slash will not be added. Please edit your question to include the WordPress `.htaccess` file from the subdirectory.

Comment: @MrWhite edited

Comment: @NicoReal I've updated my answer.

Comment: @MrWhite You're the man! Thank you so much for helping out! Is it an easy edit, if I need to have URL with trailing slash to redirect to URL without trailing slash? like for example, if I visit "/about/" it should redirect to "/about"?

Comment: @NicoReal I've updated my answer (update#2) to include a redirect to remove the trailing slash.