# Redirect URL with trailing slash to no trailing slash URL

Tags: apache, .htaccess

I have a specific page that can be viewed only if URL has trailing slash (`/blog/`). If not, it will return an error 403. So what I want is I want `/blog` to redirect to `/blog/`.

I know it's possible but I can't achieve it using .htaccess. I believe this is already questioned here but not properly answered.

Here's my root .htaccess:

```
Options -Indexes

ErrorDocument 404 /error/error404.html

DirectoryIndex index.html index.php

DirectorySlash Off

RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond $1 !/$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule (.+) $1/ [L]
```

Comment: Although your _question title_ would seem to contradict what you are actually trying to do in the question and that is to _append_ a trailing slash, not remove it. (?)

Answer (score 0):

Presumably this is related to [your earlier question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69377386/apache-look-for-index-php-in-subdirectories-if-index-html-is-not-present), which is very relevant here.
Importantly, `/blog` is a subdirectory that contains a WordPress installation and an additional `.htaccess` file with the usual WordPress (mod_rewrite) directives. This means that the mod_rewrite directives in the parent config are entirely overridden.

(Although I imagine the requirement for this may also be negated by your earlier question since it is now possible to access `/blog` without the trailing slash.)

> So what I want is I want /blog to redirect to /blog/

For this you could simply *enable* the `DirectorySlash` in the `/blog/.htaccess` file. This will allow mod_dir to append the trailing slash with a 301 redirect if required. For example:

```
# /blog/.htaccess

DirectorySlash On

# BEGIN WordPress
:
```

Alternatively, conditionally disable `DirectorySlash` in the root `.htaccess` file for everything except the `/blog` subdirectory. For example:

```
# /.htaccess

# Conditionally turn Off directory slash for everything except "/blog" 
<If "%{REQUEST_URI} !~ m#^/blog($|/)#">
    DirectorySlash Off
</If>
```